# More algebraic approach on showing that $\det(e_j,a_2,\dots,a_n) = (-1)^{j-1}\det(A^{1,j})$

Tags: linear-algebra, permutations, determinant

I'm looking to make the following argument on why $\det(e_j,a_2,\dots,a_n) = (-1)^{j-1}\det(A^{1,j})$ less handwavy. Specifically I have not figured out how to argue about the "rest of a permutation" in a more mathematical way by representing it as, for example, a composition of other two permutations as "the rest" is a bijective mapping from the set $\{a \in \mathbb{N}\mid a \neq j \land a \leq n\}$ to $\{a \in \mathbb{N}\mid a > 1 \land a\leq n\}$, which isn't (to my knowledge) a permutation in the exact sense. **Note:** In the equation $A^{i,j}$ is formed by deleting the $i$th column and $j$th row of the matrix $A$, and $e_j$ is the $j$th standard basis vector.

Currently my argument is the following: By definition $\det(e_j,a_2,\dots,a_n) = \sum_{\sigma \in S_n}(\mathrm{sgn}(\sigma))a_{1,\sigma(1)}\cdots a_{n,\sigma(n)}$, where the summand is zero if $\sigma(j) \neq 1$, as the first column of the argument matrix is the $j$th standard basis vector, and $\sigma$ is a permutation on the elements $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$. Thus let $T = \{\sigma \in S_n \mid \sigma(j) = 1\}$, so that $\det(e_j,a_2,\dots,a_n) = \sum_{\sigma \in S_n}(\mathrm{sgn}(\sigma))a_{1,\sigma(1)}\cdots a_{n,\sigma(n)} = \sum_{\sigma \in T}(\mathrm{sgn}(\sigma))a_{1,\sigma(1)}\cdots a_{j,\sigma(j)}\cdots a_{n,\sigma(n)}$, where $a_{j, \sigma(j)} = 1$, and $\sigma$ is in fact a transposition between $j$ and $1$, so that $(\mathrm{sgn}(\sigma))a_{1,\sigma(1)}\cdots a_{j,\sigma(j)}\cdots a_{n,\sigma(n)} = (-1)^{j-1}(\mathrm{sgn}(\sigma'))\underbrace{a_{1,\sigma'(1)}\cdots a_{n,\sigma'(n)}}_{=n-1}$, where $(-1)^{j-1}$ is from the $j - 1$ inversions resulting from the swap of $j$ and $1$, and $\sigma'$ represents rest of the permutation $\sigma$.

As $a_{j, \sigma(j)} = 1$ for all $\sigma \in T$, we have effectively removed the $j$th component from each of the argument matrix's column vectors, as we are no longer consider any other $a_{j, k}$ for $k  = \sigma(j) \neq 1$. Thus $\det(e_j,a_2,\dots,a_n)$ is in effect given by $(-1)^{j-1}\sum_{\sigma' \in T'}(\mathrm{sgn}(\sigma'))a_{1,\sigma'(1)}\cdots a_{n,\sigma'(n)}$, where $T' = \{\text{rest of the permutation } \sigma\mid \sigma \in T\}$, which is equal to $(-1)^{j-1}\det(A^{1,j})$

Comment: I wonder if doing induction on the dimension of the matrix, starting at $n=2$ would be the way to go.

Comment: The easiest way is to use Laplace expansion along the first column. Or is this part of your attempt to prove Laplace expansion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First prove that
$$\det(e_1, a_2, \dots, a_n) = \det(A^{1, 1})$$
using column operations followed by the characterization of the determinant: $\det$ is the unique map $\det \colon M(n, \mathbb{C}) \to \mathbb{C}$ that is alternating, multilinear, and satisfies $\det(I) = 1$.
From your permutation formula for the determinant it is possible to deduce that $\det(A^T) = \det(A)$. Thus swapping two rows multiplies the determinant by a minus sign. With this you can deduce that
$$\det(e_j, a_2, \dots, a_n) = (-1)^{j - 1}\det(A^{1, j}).$$
To deduce this, you swap row $j$ up $j - 1$ times so that it becomes row $1$, and then you apply the previous result.